# How To Add A Map For Every Product View Page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-page, google-map

I have a coffee store based shop in magento . Now i want to show the map for each coffee shop in the product view

[image]

every store has its different location for google map. any help would be very thankful and appreciable. there are different store google map store extension but i want to show on the product page and each product has its different google map location how we can do this?

I can copy a iframe google map which place in the static blog and called the static block in the `view.phtml page` but it is for only one product i want to call different maps based on different product

Comment: I think to create static blocks according to your needs. Then show the blocks on store basis on the product page after the info or short description block.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create 2 attributes: **"lat"** and **"lng"** *(latitude, longitude)* (see here http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-create-an-attribute-and-apply-it-to-products.html)

Then copy `/templates/catalog/product/view.phtml` to your theme folder and insert this code into right place. (code from example of google map api
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple)

```
 <?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $lat = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getLat(), 'lat');
    $lng = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getLat(), 'lng');
?>

<div id="map"></div>
<script>

    function initMap() {
      var myLatLng = {lat: <?php echo $lat; ?>, lng: <?php echo $lng; ?>};

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatLng
      });

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
      });
    }
</script>
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may like using this module : https://github.com/Smile-SA/magento2-module-map that allow to wrap Google Map more easily in Magento.

An example usage can be found here : 
* Template : https://github.com/Smile-SA/magento2-module-store-locator/blob/master/view/frontend/templates/view/map.phtml and here 
* Block : https://github.com/Smile-SA/magento2-module-store-locator/blob/master/Block/View/Map.php

More information available here : https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite-for-retailer, but you will require only the smile/module-map for your use case